# How can I link a group of galleries through a single image using Views?

Tags: 7, views, media

I found a great article titled ["How to Create an Image Gallery in Drupal"](http://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-in-drupal) and at the end the author was sketching the posibility of its intregration with Views.My intention is to display a grid View of single images that represents the full contents (the galleries) that I created thanks to that article,and when you click on each one they take you to its respective group of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following on the View:

1. Add your custom "path" field and set it to be hidden (Exclude from Display).
2. Add The image field. Under "Rewrite results" set it to "Output this field as a link" and use the token for the previously hidden field.

This will allow you to define what will each image do when clicked.

Comment: Dear Jorge,First,Thanks a lot for your quick answer!I was reading the docs of Views but still I am not in the right way...When you speak about the custom "path" field..what do you mean?...what is it?...I have no problems with the second step,I mean,with the Image field...but it is the result of the first step...the token for the previously hidden field.